# Javascript print SQL first item in ResultSet without comma, then all others with comma

Tags: javascript, sql, arrays, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

```
create procedure my_stored_procedure(TABLE VARCHAR)
  returns varchar
  language javascript
  as
    $$

var sql_col_list = `select distinct key_name from TABLE;`
results = snowflake.execute({sqlText: sql_col_list});

while (results.next())
{
     script += ',' + results.getColumnValue(1) + '\n';
}
```

Current output:

```
, column1
, column2
, column3
```

Desired output:

```
  column1
, column2
, column2
```

How can I do this in javascript within the sql stored procedure? I would like to not have to execute the query more than once because the actual query is computationally intensive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add boolean check if this first or not:

```
var sql_col_list = `select distinct key_name from TABLE;`
results = snowflake.execute({sqlText: sql_col_list});

var isFirst = true;

while (results.next())
{
      if(isFirst)
      {
        script += results.getColumnValue(1) + '\n';
        isFirst = false;
        continue;
      }
     script += ',' + results.getColumnValue(1) + '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A poor solve it after the fact solution, remove it:

```
> ',a,b,c'.replace(/^,/,'');
'a,b,c'
>
```

another option is to build an array of the wanted parts, and then use join

```
> ['a','b','c'].join(',\n');
'a,\nb,\nc'
>
```

and if you want the trailing newline:

```
> ['a','b','c'].join(',\n')+'\n';
'a,\nb,\nc\n'
>
```

OR you could get Snowflake to do it for you:

```
SELECT listagg( DISTINCT key_name, ',\\n') || '\\n'
FROM VALUES
   ('apple'),('cat'),('apple'),('cat'),('dog') t(key_name);
```

| LISTAGG( DISTINCT KEY_NAME, ',\N')|| '\N' |
| --- |
| apple,\ncat,\ndog\n |

Answer (score 0):

using your sp, i would remove the first result from the loop so it is:

```
create or replace procedure my_stored_procedure(TABLE VARCHAR)
  returns varchar
  language javascript
  as
    $$

var sql_col_list = `select distinct key_name from TABLE;`
results = snowflake.execute({sqlText: sql_col_list});
var script = '';

results.next()
script += results.getColumnValue(1)

while (results.next())
{
       script += ',' + results.getColumnValue(1) + '\n';
}
return script;
$$;
```